# Error for hosting Nodejs website in IIS

Tags: node.js, iis-7.5, iis-10, windows-server-2016

I recently upgraded my IIS v 7.5.7600 to v 10.0.14. My Nodejs websites were perfectly fine with the old version of IIS. However, I have some unknown errors for hosting the same websites in IIS 10. I can't even go to the "Modules" in IIS 10. I receive this message below when I click on te modules to see iisnode. 
The server is 64 bit Windows Server 2016. [image: this]

The websites work locally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that IIS URL Rewrite has not been installed. The issue has been solved after the installation of URL Rewrite.